# VBA Dictionary remove item

Tags: vba, dictionary, combobox

I am trying to remove items from the dictionary which are already selected from the comboboxes. I have a following code but i dont know what the problem is.It gives me an object required error at d2("v" & cbnr).Remove (ss).

a is an Array.

```
Sub cb_pop2(cbnr As Integer)
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim d2 as object
Dim ss as string    

Set d2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
d2("v" & cbnr) = a

For i = cbnr To 5
UserForm1.Controls("ComboBox" & i).Clear

    For j = cbnr To i
        ss = UserForm1.Controls("ComboBox" & j - 1).Value
        d2("v" & cbnr).Remove (ss)
    Next j
    UserForm1.Controls("ComboBox" & i).List = d2("v" & cbnr).keys
    UserForm1.Controls("ComboBox" & i).ListIndex = 0
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: This is a little confusing. At the point of `d2("v" & cbnr) = a` you have a dictionary called `d2` with one record in it (`d2.Count`). That record as a *Key* of `"v" & cbnr` and an *Item*- of `a` (no idea what **a** is). The only thing you can remove is that one key/item pair like `d2.Remove("v" & cbnr)`. So you can see how you cannot remove key/item pairs from the combox since they were never in the dictionary to begin with.

Comment: a is an Array and list source for all comboboxes.

Answer (score 7):

This is an example of using dictionary in VBA

```
Sub TestDictionary()
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For x = 1 To 5
    Key = "Start" & x
    Value = 0 + x
    If Not dict.Exists(Key) Then
        dict.Add Key, Value
    End If
Next x
For Each k In dict.keys
    MsgBox (dict(k))
Next
    If dict.Exists(Key) Then
        dict.Remove Key
    Else
        'You can put here a code to show errors 
    End If

End Sub
```

I suggest you to use an If-Then  to check "Key" before adding/removing so you will able to intercept errors depending by "wrong Key" or "not present Key"